# Add Html Text to Html5 Canvas

Tags: html, canvas

I got from a different Application a html formatted Text from user input.
(With font b br ul and so on, different fonts and colors in one fragment )

I would like to write this on a canvas.

like `context.write("<b>Hello</b> World <font...>more text </font>");`

how can i do this?

Comment: Do you need to write it on the `canvas`?  Are you going to manipulate it in some way?  Otherwise you could just create a `div` with the text in it and position it in front of your canvas.

Comment: Yes i need to put in in the canvas. I want to animate it with some other elements.

Comment: Yes i need font. It is the output from an flex html textbox.

Comment: **See Also**: [HTML5 Canvas API - formatting individual words with italics](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24163211/1366033)

Answer (score 2):

First, you'll have to make available to the canvas all the fonts you are using `@font-face` if needed.

Then you'll have to describe all the operations needed to draw the text, remember canvas is just a drawing surface. You'll have to iterate over these steps:

1. Specify the font to be used: (same syntax as the CSS font property)

   ```js
   context.font = "12px Arial bold"
   ```
2. Measure the string that will be drawn to know where to place the next one:

   ```js
   context.measureText(txt).width
   ```
3. Draw your text (fill or stroke):

   ```js
   context.fillText(txt, x, y)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This should help

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Drawing_text_using_a_canvas

Though you would need to read the formats from the html and re-apply using this method.