# How to add canvas as bold for specific text in a multiline string?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, jcanvascript

Is it possible?
html:

```
   <canvas>  </canvas>
```

js:

```
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
     ctx.font = "10pt  bold Courier";
       var input ="99%" + "More teams partcipated in the contest of asia tournament"
       ctx.fillText(input, 100, 100);
```

O/p: 99 is dynamic data from service.
  99%  - should be bold and highlight

More teams Participated in 
the contest of Asia tournament // normal text

Comment: You have to change the `ctx.font` before each `ctx.fillText()`.

Comment: @PHPglue how to change for the particular text such as 99% so in that  i have confused?

Comment: Try solution provided in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24163211/html5-canvas-api-italic-word

Comment: **See Also**: [HTML5 Canvas API - formatting individual words with italics](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24163211/1366033)

Answer (score 2):

Try doing the following:

```js
// get canvas / context
var can = document.getElementById('my-canvas');
var ctx = can.getContext('2d')

// draw first text
var text = '99%';
ctx.font = 'bold 12pt Courier';
ctx.fillText(text, 50, 50);

// measure text
var textWidth = ctx.measureText(text).width;

// draw second text
ctx.font = 'normal 12pt Courier';
ctx.fillText(' invisible', 50 + textWidth, 50);
```

```html
<canvas id="my-canvas" width="250" height="150"></canvas>
```